# Prolog exercise: filter sequence of consecutive elements

Tags: list, prolog

I am getting mad of prolog. I have to do an exercise which is `filter_Sequences(N,L1,L2)` and then SWI Prolog will answer in `L2` the result of the elements which are consecutive in `L1`, I give you an example to explain it:

```
?- filter_sequence(2,[a,b,b,c,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d],L2).
L2= [b,b,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c]
```

It means 3 because of is the element `N`, is an integer which is the lowest rate of consecutive elements and then the list with 3 b's 3 a's and 4 b's and more digits but `L2` keeps just the consecutive elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post some code, please, not just your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a high-level approach.

```prolog
mad(N,S,L2):- nrle(N,S,L),expand(L,L2).
```

right? `nrle` does an RLE encoding, but only keeps entries with at least `N` duplicates.

```prolog
nrle(_,[],[]).
nrle(N,[A|B],L):- nrle(N,B,A-1,L).
nrle(N,[A|B],E-I,L):- 
    A = E -> I1 is I+1, nrle(N,B,E-I1,L) ;
    I >= N -> L=[E-I|L2], nrle(N,B,A-1,L2) ;
    nrle(N,B,A-1,L).
nrle(N,[],E-I,[E-I]):- I >= N.
nrle(N,[],E-I,[]):- I < N.
```

testing:

```prolog
9 ?- nrle(3,[a,b,b,b,c,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d],L2).
L2 = [b-3, a-3, b-4] ;
false.

10 ?- nrle(4,[a,b,b,b,c,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d],L2).
L2 = [b-4] ;
false.

11 ?- nrle(2,[a,b,b,b,c,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d],L2).
L2 = [b-3, a-3, b-4, c-2] ;
false.
```

Now, `expand`:

```prolog
expand([A-1|C],[A|D]):- expand(C,D).
expand([A-B|C],[A|D]):- B>1, B1 is B-1, expand([A-B1|C],D).
expand([],[]).
```

And then,

```prolog
25 ?- mad(3,[a,b,b,b,c,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,d],L2).
L2 = [b, b, b, a, a, a, b, b, b, b] ;
false.
```

See, Prolog is fun.

Comment: it works, the other solution doesnt work as I asked but thanks anyway

Comment: @user3006475 I take it you're no longer mad of Prolog? Maybe getting mad *about* Prolog even?.. :)

Comment: I get a warning about singleton variable E in the last line of nrle code...How can I avoid it?

Comment: @user3006475 replace `E` with `_`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: As Will Ness has pointed out, this solution misses the N parameter.

1. Get the first element from the list
2. Compare with the second element from the list
3. If the two elements are equal:

   1. place the two elements in the output
   2. and any following element that is also equal
4. Otherwise discard the first element
5. Repeat until the list is exhausted.

In Prolog:

```prolog
% untested
delete_singles([], []).
delete_singles([A|T], O) :-
     (    T = [A|T1]
     ->   O = [A, A|O1],
          delete_singles(T1, A, O1)
     ;    delete_singles(T, O)).

delete_singles([], _, []).
delete_singles([H|T], A, O) :-
     (    H = A
     ->   O = [A|O1],
          delete_singles(T, A, O1)
     ;    delete_singles([H|T], O)).
```

Comment: did you miss the requirement of minimal length of the repeating sub-sequence? :)

Comment: @WillNess, opps, yes, I though it was always 2.